# Download Android code for Contacts application

Tags: android, git, android-source

I am trying to download Android source code for Contact,Dialer and CallLog applications from the git repository. I have tried the following on my mac(running SnowLeopard):
1. Create a bin dir and a android dir for putting all the downloaded files
2. Added both of the directories to the PATH environment variable
3. run the following commands to get the repo script and make it executable:

```
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

4. cd android dir
5. run `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b froyo`

When I run this command, I am getting the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/bin/repo", line 595, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Users/xxxx/bin/repo", line 562, in main
    _Init(args)
  File "/Users/xxxx/bin/repo", line 181, in _Init
    _CheckGitVersion()
  File "/Users/xxxx/bin/repo", line 210, in _CheckGitVersion
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 593, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/subprocess.py", line 1079, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

A quick google search tells that I need to install git-core library. Unfortunately, I don't know if that is the real problem or not and if so, how to install it.

Comment: How do I install git-core? Can you give me the instructions for the same in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to install git for OS X. You can find a handy installer here: http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/

As long as the git directory appears in your $PATH (I can't remember if the installer does this or you'd need to do it manually), that python script should find it when it's executed. Alternatively, you could hack the python script so that it knows exactly where git is.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts, you will see that the basic git command is just:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts
```

that way you clone the Contacts repository into your current directory. And yes, you need to have git installed for this. If you just want to work on individual parts of the platform and don't want to check out everything then you can work with just git and you don't have to use the `repo` tool at all.