# Android Source: Repo not displaying any initialization message

Tags: android, build, repository

I've followed the instructions Google has provided on downloading the Source Tree, but after I run the command

`$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.3.7_r1`

and I receive the following error message :

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.3.7_r1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 690, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 657, in main_Init(args)
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 189, in _Init_CheckGitVersion()
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 214, in _CheckGitVersion
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What did I do wrong? Or is this just an error on behalf of Repo?

UPDATE: Now that I've installed Python 2.7, I still have almost the exact same error message:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.3.7_r1
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 690, in <module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 657, in main_Init(args)
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 189, in _Init_CheckGitVersion()
File "/Users/roboguy12/bin/repo", line 214, in _CheckGitVersion
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I call `$ python -V` and it says Python 2.7.1, so I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download Android code for Contacts application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465094/download-android-code-for-contacts-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you might have not done a couple of things: chmod'd the repo to +x and/or put it in your $PATH statement as the first directory to look for (and could be using another version of repo).  Have you tried 'ls -al' instead?  The directory you're looking for is hidden and you need the -a argument in ls to view hidden files/directories.

UPDATE: Ah, just saw your update.  Since you're using a Mac, you need to use Python 2.7.  To do so, you'll need to MacPort it.  This website provided much help to me: [INSTALLING PYTHON 2.7, EASY_INSTALL, PIP, VIRTUALENV AND VIRTUALENVWRAPPER ON MAC OS X](http://blog.praveengollakota.com/47430655)

Comment: I called chmod a+x on it and I have added it to the PATH. The .repo folder is there when I ls -al it, but it's empty. When I try to do repo sync, it tells me that I have failed to initialize it.

EDIT: Ok, I just saw your update, I'm trying that now; I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Ok, now that I've installed Python 2.7, I get the same exact error message. I'll update my OP with the message.

Comment: Seems to me this is your issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465094/download-android-code-for-contacts-application